# server is out of memory

Tags: magento2, configuration, server-setup

I'm running magento project on c5dxlarge with 8GB RAM. storefront was working fine but suddenly server get out of memory and memory usage became 80 percent. Also I had about 300 running processes even if storefront not used

the only thing I've changed before it goes out of memory was uploading data. I have more than 25000 products.

May too much data cause the problem? and what are the causes if not data?

**Note:** I'm checking on an attribute before uploading data and do some processing through for loop. Does this cause any problems when uploading many products?

Comment: First of all what version of magento 2 are you using? i know there was data issues with 2.2.4 which i have delt with on a number of occasions. have you also tried splitting your data up into smaller files to to check to see if that would work

Comment: check in any visual tool like newrelic  etc which process is eating memory, then you can find the issue